# How do I permanently remove a default Powershell alias?

Tags: powershell

For some unknown reason, the devs included "curl" as an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, even though it is not compatible with the proper implementation of curl, which means it gets in the way when I try to make a curl request. I can remove the alias using `Remove-Item alias:curl`, but next time I start Powershell, the alias has returned. Is there a way to remove it permanently without having to run a script every time I start?

Comment: just FYI:
I have issued same command `Remove-Item alias:curl` inside windows server 2019  and it's does not appear again even after restaring

Comment: @matsonkepson that worked.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Skip this step if you already have a Powershell profile:

```
New-Item $profile -force -itemtype file
```

Then edit your profile:

```
notepad $profile
```

Add the following line to it:

```
remove-item alias:curl
```

Save, close notepad and reload the profile with the command below or close and open Powershell to apply the profile:

```
. $profile
```

Comment: Thanks. I must say it's annoying that the powershell developers didn't think this through, forcing us to now have to work around the issue in this way.

Comment: I don't think it's meant to be a 1:1 replacement. Powershell focuses on an overarching use of a defined set of parameters and automatic parameter binding (which is really great once you get into it). Providing the curl alias is to show folks accustomed to *nix that there is a curl equivalent in Powershell.

Comment: The first step can always be skipped. I just did, and got a pop-up asking if I wanted to create the file.

Comment: FYI: For some aliases, you will need to append "-Force"

Comment: The "funny" thing is that even azure docs show curl commands to quickly test out thing. Real curl commands, not `Invoke-WebRequest` syntax...

Comment: For people who googled this and want to remove their individual aliases: If I remove the alias from $profile, close the session and open it, it should be blown away without using remove-item. Or instead of closing $profile, sourcing it.

Answer (score 8):

I'd stick with using `curl.exe` instead of just `curl`. This approach doesn't rely on PowerShell running with particular profile (and PowerShell could be run with no profile at all using `-NoProfile` switch).

Comment: I could argue that in theory, powershell may eventually run on unix, where program files don't have a ".exe" extension. It makes absolutely no sense to unix people to have aliases enabled in *scripts*. I have to wonder whether that bad-design choice was deliberate to try to kill the opensource GNU software stack on windows. And why don't we at least have a "command" built-in to force the shell to look for a real program? Powershell really fails on the KISS principle.

Comment: @JohanBoulé No need for for conspiracy theories, it was just an oversight. PowerShell 6 already runs on Linux and the alias issues are partially fixed. See this links: [initialsession: remove curl and wget aliases](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/1901), [Please remove **all** built-in aliases and put them in a module](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5870), [Provide a syntax to call native binaries when its name is aliased](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1975)

Comment: None of those PRs are merged. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

add `Remove-Item alias:cur` to powershell autorun script

above XP,2003:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Documents\Msh\profile.msh
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Documents\Msh\Microsoft.Management.Automation.msh_profile.msh
```

XP,2003:

```
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\msh\profile.msh
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\msh\Microsoft.Management.Automation.msh_profile.msh
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to remove it permanently without having to run a script every time I start?

Technically, no. However, you can utilize the built-in PowerShell Profiles, which runs a script every time you load up PowerShell, to do it for you. But, at least it's not manual.

This is (part) of what I added to my `$profile.AllUsersAllHosts` file. It is similar to [megamorf's answer](https://superuser.com/a/890193/1166471) but slightly more expansive.

```
Remove-Item alias:curl
Set-Alias curl "${env:SystemRoot}\System32\curl.exe"
Set-Alias wcurl Invoke-WebRequest
```

You can do this with any of [the 6 Powershell profile files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1), but I'm the only one who uses my desktop, and I see no harm in changing it up a little. If you're not, then go with a different one with a smaller scope. The default $Profile is CurrentUserCurrentHost, so that can't hurt, I'll do the rest of it with that in mind, just substitute the code for whichever one you're changing.

Open a PowerShell terminal, as an Administrator if you can, but I'm fairly certain that the default, CurrentUSerCurrentHost, does not require admin privileges.

Then run:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $profile.currentusercurrenthost)) {
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $profile.currentusercurrenthost -Force
}
```

Then run `notepad $profile.currentusercurrenthost`

That will check to see if the file exists, if it does not, it will create the file. Then the second command will then open it with notepad.

Note: If you have VSCode or Notepad++ installed, you can open it with VSCode by typing `code $profile.currentusercurrenthost` instead of `notepad`. For notepad++ run the command `Set-Alias npp "${Env:ProgramFiles}\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` to *temporarily* create an alias for Notepad++. That way, you can simply type `npp $profile.currentusercurrenthost`, and it'll open in notepad++. It's similar with other file editors. You can also add this to your profile as well if you'd like that to be permanent.

Then add the lines as you see fit, though this first one *must* be first.
`Remove-Item alias:curl` will simply remove the existing alias curl has for Invoke-WebRequest every time you open a powershell prompt.
`Set-Alias curl "${env:SystemRoot}\System32\curl.exe"` sets curl to be an alias for curl.exe which is the *actual* cURL. It's included in Windows 10 Build 17063 and later.

I also chose to add an alias for the original Invoke-WebRequest, calling it wcurl, with `Set-Alias wcurl Invoke-WebRequest` as there may be situations when I want to use it, and don't want to type out the long string there.

So, in order, that is:

1. `Remove-Item alias:curl`
2. `Set-Alias curl "${env:SystemRoot}\System32\curl.exe"`
3. `Set-Alias wcurl Invoke-WebRequest`
4. `Set-Alias npp "${Env:ProgramFiles}\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`

Everything after #1 is optional, and the order after #1 does not matter, but #1 must be before #2, or any attempts to create an alias named curl.

If this is a brand new profile, it will be blank upon opening it, and you can add them (in order) if you want them or not. If it's not blank, I would recommend adding it towards the end, if not the end. Personally, my $Profile ends with

```
cls
pwsh -v
```

which clears the screen from the various operations it does upon boot, and shows the PowerShell version.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your powershell profile:

```
notepad $profile

if(Test-Path -Path alias:curl) { Remove-Item alias:curl }
```

Windows Powershell has this default curl alias, but Powershell Core doesn't.
If you want your profile useable for both, you should add `Test-Path` before remove.